# Is it possible to configure parse.com as backend instead of mongodb using generator "yo meanjs"?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parse-platform, meanjs, yo

i am new to MEAN js stack and was curious if there is a way to hook up parse.com as backend thru auto generated code via meanjs so i can access parse objects and execute queries

by default yo meanjs generators creates mongodb backend. i want to access parse.com data instead

any pointers would be highly appreciated - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. But not with the generator. Best path would be to use:

https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack with `Database: None`

Then use the parse REST API or JavaScript SDK. It is very simple to use as is.
http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/the-javascript-sdk-in-node-js/